# Web scraping using Pycharm Python

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape the data from this website `https://www.locatefamily.com/Street-Lists/India/index.html`. I have been trying by using several code techniques but I cannot do it please help me with the correct code in extracting data from this websites from all the pages
also I want this scraped data in csv or notepad file format

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

page_list = []
for i in range(1,60):
    domain = "https://www.locatefamily.com/Street-Lists/India/index.html"+str(i)
    page_list.append(domain)

comment_list = []
for page in page_list:
    try:
        content = requests.get(page).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
        #comment = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'rvw-bd'})

        comment = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'list-group-item'})
        print(len(comment))

        for x in range(len(comment)):
            comment_list.append(comment[x].p.text.strip())
    except:
        continue
        time.sleep(30)

print(comment_list)
print(len(comment_list))
```

Comment: I have no time to answer this question, but try using these variables in your code instead that yours```domain = f"https://www.locatefamily.com/Street-Lists/India/index-{i}.html"``` and ```comment = soup.find_all('li',{'class':'list-group-item'})```

Comment: Sorry it did not help me